# Как вывести все элементы через цикл for?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
asd = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
def test():
    for i in asd:
        return i

test()
```

При выполнении данного кода возвращает только число `1`, как вернуть `все елементы`?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что значит `вернуть все элементы` ?

Comment: То есть вывести все элементы данного словаря, но не через `print()`, так как мне нужна только функция.

Comment: Выдаёт генератор(<generator object _repl_coroutine.<locals>.test at 0x1592AF08>), как вывести сами числа?

Comment: `print(*test())`

Comment: Я хочу использовать i(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) в качестве индексов.

Comment: @RAINGM, `type(asd)` ставит все по местам. `asd` изначально `set`? В чем проблема преобразовать его к `tuple`? `tuple(set)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поменяйте `return` на `yield`

```
def test():
    for i in asd:
        yield i
```

Второй вариант

```
def test():
    return list(asd)
```